# Archiving service for large numbers of similar documents

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'd like to set up a kind of archiving service.  The idea is that I send a document (a few 10s of KB of HTML) to the service, it sends me back a short identifier, and later I can use the identifier to retrieve the document.  Many of the documents will be very similar to each other; for any one document, there might be 1000 others that overlap with it by 95%.  Thus, every time I send a document the archiving service should try to find a similar one, and just store the differences.

Does there exist a system like this already?  I would prefer something PHP/MySQL based if possible.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB comes to mind from your use case.  Read about how they store documents as JSON and how they have revisions for documents (stored in a _rev field).

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/documents.html

It will not do comparisons for you however. That responsibility would fall to you with a simple CouchDB implementation, but it does handle versions for you quite nicely.

Unfortunately I don't know any out of the box database that compares documents and then finds things that are similar and replaces them.